# how to loop in nested if else statement

Tags: c++

we are currently creating a mini game for our school project.

the game code is already done but im currently doing some introduction.

i was thinking of putting the mechanics of the game when you run the program and i want to put a menu.
ex.(press 1 to play , press 2 to exit) im already done with the code for the nested if too but i don't know the code for looping it back to asking a number if the user enter a number that's not indicated for example the number 3. I want to loop it back to asking a number until the user input a valid number.

Comment: Who is this "we" business?

Comment: `while (no_valid_choice_selected) { ... }`

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help ) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: "we" is my school mates :) anyway thanks im gonna try it. we just started our class for programming and is currently learning the basics of c++.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to exit the "if" statement, I think you want to use:

```
 continue;
```

If you are in a switch/case, you would use:

```
 break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a level.Then if your input doesn't satisfy the conditions ,then  jump that level again using **goto level** and take input again untill it satifies the conditions.

```
karim:
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    if(a==1){....do what...}
    else if(a==2) { ...do what...}
    else
     goto karim;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put all of your actions in a while() cycle and write something like that:

```
while ((key = getch()) != *exit key*){
    if (key == ...){ action 1; }
    else if (key == ...){ action 2; }
    else if (key == ...){ action 3; }
}
```